# Running PHP docker container with MYSQL container

Tags: php, mysql, docker, nginx, docker-network

I need to make my PHP docker container connect with my MYSQL container.

The steps I'm trying to execute are:

1. create a docker network:

`docker network create network-pfa`

2. run the mysql container:

`docker run --name mysql --network=network-pfa -d -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=YES mysql:5.7`

3. run the php container:

`docker run --name php --network=network-pfa -it php bash`

After these steps inside the php container bash I'm trying to connect to the mysql using the command:

`mysql -u root`

Bash error: `bash: mysql: command not found`

I have been studying docker for just a week and am trying to make a simple system using php, mysql and nginx.

My goal is to connect the three containers together and create a php file that reads some data in mysql and then using nginx to view my php result in my computer's browser (outside the containers).

Note: I am not using docker-compose yet.

Comment: `mysql` is the name of the database client program. There is no reason to suspect that it will be installed in your `php` container by default. You will need to install it, either interactively in the container with a package manager, or in the `Dockerfile`. 

I would personally install the database client on your host operating system and expose the database port from the `mysql` container so you can access the database server from the host.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is missing to install the mysql-client in your Dockerfile

For alpine

```
RUN apk add mysql-client
```

For debian based:

```
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client
```